# Telling an contains()-based XPath query to stop once it reaches a letter?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

I scrape various jobs pages for a given keyword, and extract the title and links when there are matches.

```
XPATH_MAPPING_SINGLE_PAGE = {'heading' : "//*[self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::dt][contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '%s')]"}
XPATH_MAPPING_HYPERLINKS = {'href': "//a[contains(translate(normalize-space(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '%s')]/@href",
                        'text': "//a[contains(translate(normalize-space(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '%s')]"}

import urllib2
import urlparse

import lxml.html as lh

response = urllib2_urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
root = lh.fromstring(content)
titles_and_links = get_individual_job_titles_and_hyperlinks(root, keyword)

def get_individual_job_titles_and_hyperlinks(root, keyword):
    texts = [element.text_content().strip() for element in root.xpath(XPATH_MAPPING_HYPERLINKS['text'] % keyword)]
    hrefs = root.xpath(XPATH_MAPPING_HYPERLINKS['href'] % keyword)
    return zip(texts, hrefs)
```

This is working quite reliably. Yet for a page like https://www.gosquared.com/careers/ and keyword 'Engineer', it pulls out the single Engineering job thereon, but also extracts a link to the company's Engineering blog page:

```
>>print title_and_links
[('Engineering Blog', '//engineering.gosquared.com/'), ('Software Engineer', '/careers/software-engineer/'), ('Engineering Blog', '//engineering.gosquared.com/')]
```

This is obviously happening because my XPath is `contains()`-based. Once it finds the text 'Engineer' it will deem it a match, and so explains why the 'Engineer**ing**' link is also picked up.

How do I modify my XPath so that it won't make these false positives? The updated XPath will need to know to stop right after the keyword ends and perhaps expect some punctation (space, hyphen, period, comma etc.) rather than a letter, thereby still correctly picking up link texts like:

- Engineer-Mechanical
- Chemist - Pharmaceutical
- Consultant, Healthcare Division
- etc.

Can this be done purely with XPath, without adding a regex to expect punctuation or whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming we cannot rely on any specific section on the page where the job titles may appear.

But, I'm pretty sure, you can avoid looking into `header` and `footer` elements. Check the parents:

```
//*
  [self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::dt]
  [contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '%s')]
  [not(ancestor::footer) and not(ancestor::header)]
```

This would help not to match the `Engineering Blog` in this particular case since it is in the footer.

Comment: *I am assuming we cannot rely on any specific section on the page where the job titles may appear.* - indeed, this page is just one example, and the link to the Engineering page could be anywhere.